# Mocha tests with 'esm' support for native ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, es6-modules

There is great post "[Testing native ES modules using Mocha and esm](https://web.archive.org/web/20220318155753/https://alxgbsn.co.uk/2019/02/22/testing-native-es-modules-mocha-esm/)" of Alex Gibson. Thanks him.

I've tried to use mocha with native ES modules support in my project and I had 2 different errors:

```
$ ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --require esm './test/Util.test.js'

TypeError [ERR_VM_DYNAMIC_IMPORT_CALLBACK_MISSING]: A dynamic import callback was not specified.
    at exports.importModuleDynamicallyCallback (internal/process/esm_loader.js:41:9)
    at formattedImport (/.../node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:6:23)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (/.../node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:23:14)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/.../node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:33:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (/.../node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:427:19)
    ...
```

```
$ /usr/bin/node /.../node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -r esm --ui bdd --reporter \ 
  /.../PhpStorm/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js \ 
  /.../test/Util.test.js

TypeError: Invalid host defined options
    at formattedImport (/.../node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:6:23)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (/.../node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:23:14)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/.../node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:33:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (/.../node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:427:19)
    ...
```

Answer (score 11):

From what I learned in the past 2 hours:

### package.json

```json
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

### tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
    }
}
```

### .mocharc.json

```json
{
    "node-option": [
        "experimental-specifier-resolution=node",
        "loader=ts-node/esm"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: I think the reason for the error is a conflict between `--require esm` option in `mocha` arguments and other methods of indicating that sources are ES6 modules (`*.mjs` or `type` option in `package.json`). My current tests have `.mjs` extensions and the same error is occured without `"type": "module"` in `package.json`

### old staff

I've looked up for the reason and this is the reason - my own `package.json`:

```
"type": "module"
```

Note from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html):

> Node.js treats JavaScript code as CommonJS modules by default. Authors can tell Node.js to treat JavaScript code as ECMAScript modules via the .mjs file extension, the package.json "type" field, or the --input-type flag.

Just remove `"type": "module"` from your `package.json` and `mocha` will run tests with `esm` support as described in Alex Gibson's post.

This is my test repo with code to try: [flancer64/so_mocha_esm](https://github.com/flancer64/so_mocha_esm)

Comment: I can't remove `"type": "module"`, because I actually want to generate ESM modules as an end product. I'm also working in TypeScript, and having no luck so far trying to get mocha, ts-node, esm, and/or the `--experimental-specifier-resolution` flag working together happily.

Comment: @kshetline, just try to leave one only flag of ES6 sources: `"type": "module"` in `package.json` or `--require esm` option in `mocha` arguments. `mocha` is failed when both variants present.

Comment: I've tried all permutations and combinations... still no luck! For the moment I'm settling for a very sad hack that modifies my package.json via sed-like search & replace to change `"type"` to `"commonjs"`, run my tests, then fix package.json back to `"module"`. Ugh.

Comment: I fixed the "invalid host defined options" error by leaving type:module in package.json and instead renaming the problematic file .js instead of .esm.js.

Comment: I just had the same problem, even without `"type": "module"`.

Downgrading Mocha from version 9.x.x to 8.3.0 solved the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that downgrading `mocha` from `v9.0.x` to `v8.4.x` solve the issue. Thank you @RemiX,

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution after a countless number of experiments and DuckDuckGo searches :)

`mocha --loader=ts-node/esm 'test/**/*.{ts,js}'`

P.S. https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007

Answer (score 2):

this on works for me

```
"test": "mocha --require ts-node/register './src/test/**/*.ts'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across same issue and figured out that I only have these options to make it work.

1. Downgrade `mocha` version from `9.x.x` to `8.3.0`, as suggested by @RemiX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261239/mocha-tests-with-esm-support-for-native-es6-modules#comment120162973_642612400), or
2. Add `experimental-specifier-resolution=node` with `loader=ts-node/esm` in your `mocharc.node-option` as suggesteed in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jordansexton/2a0c3c360aa700cc9528e89620e82c3d#file-mocharc-json)

Hope that helps

Comment: Adds nothing which was not already answered here