# Mocking es6 with mocha in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, testdoublejs

I am struggling to properly stub/mock unit tests when using es6 modules along with a project with mixed .js and .ts files.

According to [this post](https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2021-10-29-testing-esm-with-mocha-and-testdouble/), `testdouble` should be able to provide the ESM mocking I need. However, it requires using `--loader=testdouble` to work, and I am currently using `--loader=ts-node/esm`. If I attempt to replace `ts-node/esm`, it is unable to find Typescript files:

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module
> '/Users/repos/my-repo/src/models/connectionModel.js'
> imported from
> /Users/repos/my-repo/test/constants.tjs

(`connectionModel` is ts and imported as `.js` per esm convention)

Due to project requirements, I would need the project to be compiled in es6+, so removing `type: module` or setting `module: cjs` are not viable options for me.

Is there a viable way to use both loaders, or some other viable way to mock with es6?

package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
     "test": mocha test/*.js test/*.spec.ts -r dotenv/config
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es2016",
     "module": "es6,
     "moduleResolution": "node16"
     "allowJs": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
     "esm": true
  }
  "include": [
     "./src/**/*",
     "test/**/*/.ts",
     "test/**/*.js"
  }
}
```

.mocharc.json: (grabbing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730199))

```
{
   "node-option": [
      "experimental-specifier-resolution=node",
      "loader=ts-node/esm"
   ]
}
```